# SVG render issues on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

We've designed a 9 slice scaling SVG to use as container background in our web application. It renders perfectly on the latest version of Chrome, Edge, Opera and even IE 11. But we encounter render issues on Firefox (tested on version 40 & 42).

Here's the SVG code: http://jsfiddle.net/0g5sjuyv/

[image: On Chrome]

But here's how it's rendered on Firefox:
[image: On Firefox]

As you can see, the right and bottom edges are not shown at all. First, I thought there's a problem with the applied mask, but there wasn't (**Edit: It seems there IS**). Then I thought maybe Firefox does not support applying transforms directly on `<use>` elements but it seems that's not the cause of this problem either.

I would be grateful if you could shed some light on this matter.

Comment: If I remove the mask the line *does* appear to me in FF. Just pointing out that the problem is there: http://jsfiddle.net/9g01z2u3/

Comment: Thank you @Duopixel You're right, I missed that. It seems Firefox has its own rules for SVG masks. Any idea how I can adapt it so that it works well on all modern browsers? I initially got the idea of this method from http://w3.eleqtriq.com/2014/03/the-holy-grail-of-image-scaling/

Comment: Haven't looked in detail but it could be [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=537623)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Duopixel and @RobertLongson, after hours of struggling, I finally came up with a working solution. It seems to render correctly on all modern browsers. It needs cleaning up though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <style type="text/css">
        .mask {
        fill: white;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 100px;
        }

        .fl {
        fill: #01A7CC;
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <mask id="mask-left-right">
            <rect class="mask" width="300px" height="100%" x="-100px" />
        </mask>
        <mask id="mask-right">
            <g>
                <svg x="-100%">
                    <rect class="mask" width="300px" height="100%" x="-100px" transform="scale(-1,1)" />
                </svg>
            </g>
        </mask>
        <mask id="mask-top-bottom">
            <rect class="mask" width="100%" height="300px" y="-100px" />
        </mask>
        <mask id="mask-bottom">
            <g>
                <svg y="-100%">
                    <rect class="mask" width="100%" height="300px" y="-100px" transform="scale(1,-1)" />
                </svg>
            </g>
        </mask>
        <mask id="mask-center">
            <rect class="mask" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </mask>
        <symbol id="bottomLeft" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
            <path class="fl" d="M0,150v45c0,2.8,2.3,5,5,5l45.3,0l0-2H17.7v-3l-10.8,0c-2.7,0-4.9-1.2-4.9-3.9V150L0,150z" />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="bottom">
            <rect class="fl" x="50" y="0" width="100%" height="2" />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="right">
            <rect class="fl" x="0" y="50" width="2" height="100%" />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="topRight" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
            <polygon class="fl" points="200,50 200,45.4 154.6,0 150,0 150,2 152.5,2 198,47.5 198,50 " />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="bottomRight" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
            <path class="fl" d="M198,150l0,25.3l0,11.5c0,2.7-2.2,4.9-4.9,4.9h-4.3v2.3c0,2.7-1.2,3-3.9,3l-34.9,0l0,3h14.6h4.4h17.5c2.8,0,4-1.3,4-4.1v-2.4h4.5c2.8,0,5-2.3,5-5l0-11.7l0-26.8L198,150z" />
        </symbol>
    </defs>
    <!-- top-left corner: -->
    <path class="fl" d="M50.3,0H5C2.3,0,0,2.3,0,5v45l2,0V8.9C2,6.2,4.2,5,6.9,5h43.3L50.3,0z" />

    <!-- bottom-left corner: -->
    <g transform="scale(1, -1)">
        <svg x="0" y="-100%">
            <use xlink:href="#bottomLeft" width="200" height="200" y="-200" transform="scale(1, -1)" />
        </svg>
    </g>

    <!-- top-right corner: -->
    <g transform="scale(-1, 1)">
        <svg x="-100%" y="0">
            <use xlink:href="#topRight" width="200" height="200" x="-200" transform="scale(-1, 1)" />
        </svg>
    </g>

    <!-- bottom-right corner: -->
    <g transform="scale(-1, -1)">
        <svg x="-100%" y="-100%">
            <use xlink:href="#bottomRight" width="200" height="200" y="-200" x="-200" transform="scale(-1, -1)" />
        </svg>
    </g>

    <!-- top edge: -->
    <rect class="fl" x="50.2" y="0" width="100%" height="2" mask="url(#mask-top-bottom)" />
    <!-- bottom edge: -->
    <rect class="fl" width="100%" height="2" y="-100%" mask="url(#mask-bottom)" transform="scale(1,-1)" />
    <!-- right edge: -->
    <rect class="fl" height="100%" width="2" x="-100%" mask="url(#mask-right)" transform="scale(-1,1)" />
    <!-- left edge: -->
    <rect class="fl" width="2" height="100%" mask="url(#mask-left-right)" />
</svg>
```